# Is go-ethereum performance much affected by linux filesystem choice?

Tags: go-ethereum, linux

Storage performance often seems to be a bottleneck when running a geth node, even when running on SSDs.

Does anyone know of performance comparisons under different linux filesystem choices? By default I find myself running cloud instances under xfs, but might another choice be preferable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK could be 3 things or worse. 1 Memory Fault or Not Enough Caching Memory, 2 Network performance and uptime to server, this sounds a bit generic, but a fast network card change, some memory, and making sure the SSD is a minimum of 2 TB and that will run ya.Maybe I am wrong, but this definitely sounds like a performance issue, and that when the instances of the cloud are running, that it is able to function and make the grade.
The Linux OS has always been hard working yet when it dies it dies, and well, if you use the kali pentester builds, and or the Ubuntu 22.04 More commonly available you really need to know how many extras are taking space, and is it worth the time to condense it to a USB Read only Memory Portable OS running on a Virtual Service, as this may eliminate outside resources from being added after launch and keep things running tight, with SSD Drives as Archival and Storage only FORMATTED SCRATCH DRIVES.
AM I hard core enough yet? LOL